# My website doesn't print correctly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, printing, printing-web-page

I've created a local website to be used as a database where I work.  It's made using Rails 3.2, and TwitterBootstrap for most of the CSS.  The problem is, if I want to print the view on my browser by going to file-print, or tools-print, or rightclick-print (depending on the browser), the print preview looks completely different than the actual browser page does.  For example, I have my "Index" view loaded with a nice table that has 6-8 columns, but when I print almost all of the information in the columns disapears and random code pops up in random places, including the URL, some SQL, and some folder paths where the links belong.  I just want to be able to print the page as it looks in the browser (without having to do a print screen every time).

Comment: Can you please paste your code in this question ? or Better give url of jsbin or jsfiddle to touch your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I need to set up a CSS specially for printing.  Then inserting the css link into my HTML header with media="print".

As shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp